# How to stop onchange event to read placeholder default value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have noticed that the onChangeText event before reading user input, it does read the props value that I have displayed on place holder as "enter value" and updates the same as the initial useState value for Qrcode. I don't want onChangeText to add a placeholder value into useState as it hints me from checking if a user added input by useState value as a placeholder value is added in useState for Qrcode. So is there any way to stop onChangeText from reading placeholder value into useState?

```js
function Rest(props) {
  const [Qrcode, setQrCode] = useState("");

  function SaveQrcode(enteredKey) {
    setQrCode(enteredKey);
  }

  return <TextInput placeholder={props.qrcode} onChangeText={SaveQrcode} />;
}

export default Rest;
```

Comment: It shouldn't add the placeholder to state. `onChangeText` returns the changed text which is the only thing updating state. If you were using `onChange` instead I might expect to see a variation on the problem you're having. Note: in your example you have one too-many closing `}`. Maybe your app is crashing and doing something odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `placeholder` never comes to the `onChangeText` method. Probably you have got another issue. In the following codes, you can find a simple pure function component of using `TextInput` and a *visual logger*. The placeholder doesn't affect to the state at all, neither from local state nor from props.

```js
import React from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, TextInput, View, Text} from 'react-native';

const TextInputExample = ({ p = 'default_placeholder' }) => {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState('');
  const [list, setList] = React.useState([]);
  
  const onChangeText = (t) => {
    setText(t);
    setList(l => [...l, t]);
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={onChangeText}
        value={text}
        placeholder={p}
        keyboardType="numeric"
      />
      <View style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
        {list.map((txt, idx) => (
          <View key={`prev_txt_${idx}`}>
            <Text>{txt}</Text>
          </View>
        ))}
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    height: 40,
    margin: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
  },
});

export default TextInputExample;
```

**Hint**: The `View` with the `marginTop: 20` is just a visual logger.